# Flyway migration on deployment: Illegal call to close() detected

Tags: java, deployment, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, flyway

We're building a Java EE 6 `.ear` application running on GlassFish (3.1.2.2b5) and use Flyway (3.2.1) to manage our database schema. This happens on deployment of the `.ear` - There's an article on the web called ["Easy Database Migrations using Flyway, Java EE 6 and GlassFish"](http://www.hascode.com/2013/04/easy-database-migrations-using-flyway-java-ee-6-and-glassfish/) which nicely outlines how to do it. We've minimally adopted the migrator code, in essence only changing/removing some of the logging:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class FlywayMigrator {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FlywayMigrator.class.getName());

    @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/myDS")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    private void onStartup() {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            LOG.severe("Cannot migrate, no datasource configured!");
            throw new EJBException("Cannot migrate, no datasource configured!");
        }
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
        flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);
        flyway.migrate();
    }

}
```

Now the thing is that this works pretty well - not to say perfect - migration-wise. It does, however, cause three identical warnings to be printed in the log, every time:

```
[#|2015-06-08T13:40:23.400+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.com.sun.enterprise.loader|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Illegal call to close() detected
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader$ProtectedJarFile.close(ASURLClassLoader.java:923)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.JarFileClassPathLocationScanner.findResourceNames(JarFileClassPathLocationScanner.java:41)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner.findResourceNames(ClassPathScanner.java:161)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner.scanForResources(ClassPathScanner.java:73)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.Scanner.scanForResources(Scanner.java:53)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.callback.SqlScriptFlywayCallback.<init>(SqlScriptFlywayCallback.java:76)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1315)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:919)
    at (...).FlywayMigrator.onStartup(FlywayMigrator.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1009)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:113)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCallback(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:138)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:964)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:393)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:376)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$100(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:79)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:719)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:451)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:216)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
|#]
```

Line 32 of FlywayMigrator is - unsurprisingly - the `flyway.migrate();` line.

My question is: How can we get rid of those warnings? I have found [a very similar looking issue which happened on an older version of Glassfish (2.1.1), but no reason or solution is stated there](http://w3facility.org/question/flyway-illegal-call-to-close-detected/). It's not mission-critical but desirable to have these warnings disappear and besides, it would be very nice to understand their root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably very little you can do to get rid of the pesky message except for not allowing Flyway to scan for update scripts. the code that gets called (by Flyway) looks like this

```
public void close() {
    // nothing
    _logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Illegal call to close() detected", new Throwable());
}
```

As you can see Flyway is not the culprit here (and there's nothing you could do about it)

Comment: On a second thought, you could setup your logger level to error (or fatal) and thus make these messages not to appear.